# How to pass nested data to ViewModel layer using Room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm new to using Room and am using it to persist a weather response from the DarkSky API.  The response object is shown here:

```
data class WeatherResponse(
        val currently: Currently,
        val daily: Daily,
        val flags: Flags,
        val hourly: Hourly,
        val latitude: Double,
        val longitude: Double,
        val minutely: Minutely,
        val offset: Double,
        val timezone: String
)
```

I have been able to successfully pass the Currently data to the ViewModel and display it on screen using this Currently entity:

```
const val CURRENT_WEATHER_ID = 0

@Entity(tableName = "current_weather")
data class Currently(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "apparentTemperature")
        val apparentTemperature: Double,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "cloudCover")
        val cloudCover: Double,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "dewPoint")
        val dewPoint: Double,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "humidity")
        val humidity: Double,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "icon")
        val icon: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "nearestStormBearing")
        val nearestStormBearing: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "nearestStormDistance")
        val nearestStormDistance: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "ozone")
        val ozone: Double,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "precipIntensity")
        val precipIntensity: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "precipProbability")
        val precipProbability: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "pressure")
        val pressure: Double,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "summary")
        val summary: String,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "temperature")
        val temperature: Double,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "time")
        val time: Long,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "uvIndex")
        val uvIndex: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "visibility")
        val visibility: Double,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "windBearing")
        val windBearing: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "windGust")
        val windGust: Double,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "windSpeed")
        val windSpeed: Double
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    var id: Int = CURRENT_WEATHER_ID
}
```

and this CurrentWeatherDao:

```
@Dao
interface CurrentWeatherDao {

    // UPdate or inSERT.  There can only ever be one Currently weather object in the db
    // so if it doesn't exist, insert it, and if it does, update it.
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun upsert(weatherEntry : Currently)

    // select everything from the table where the ID matches CURRENT_WEATHER_ID
    // This should only ever be one thing, since there's only one Currently in the table
    @Query("select * from current_weather where id = $CURRENT_WEATHER_ID")
    fun getWeather() : LiveData<Currently>
}
```

I assume this can be applied to the other objects in the response.  My question is, how can I also persist and have access to the offset and the timezone from the weather response in the ViewModel?

Comment: you can use ```@Embedded``` according  to [room document](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#nested-objects)

Comment: I looked into that, but didn't understand how it would apply to my situation.  Can you elaborate?